# How to access model.field in template? django

Tags: python, django

I started learning django few days ago and trying to build my first blog.

My problem is that I decided to add an extra field for my categories (subheading), which I want to be in my template, but can't understand how to do it.

my **models.py**

```
from django.db import models


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    subheading = models.CharField(max_length=160)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body = models.TextField()
    link = models.TextField()
    categories = models.ManyToManyField("Category", related_name="posts")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from blog.models import Post, Category

def blog_category(request, category):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(
        categories__name__contains=category
    ).order_by(
        'title'
    )
    context = {
        "category": category,
        "posts": posts
    }
    return render(request, "blog_category.html", context)
```

The only way **category.name** or **category.subheading** are displayed in template (by the teacher) is inside {% for post in posts %} {% endfor %}:

```
{% for post in posts %}
{% for category in post.categories.all %}
{{ category.subheading }} 
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

In this case, if there are 10 posts on category page, subheading repeats 10 times. I only need to print 1 to describe category.

Is there a way to call **category.subheading** outside of {% for post in posts %} ? Or somehow to print only one result.

p.s. sorry for my primitive English level.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a [**`Prefetch`** object [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch):

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

def blog_category(request, category):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(
        categories__name__contains=category
    ).prefetch_related(
        Prefetch(
            'categories',
            Category.objects.filter(name__contains=category)
            to_attr='relevant_categories'
        )
    ).order_by(
        'title'
    )
    # …
```

In your template, you can then render this with:

```
    {% for post in posts %}
        {% for category in post.relevant_categories %}  
            {{ category.subheading }} 
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! In this case the problem is that the subheading repeats as many times as there are posts on the category page, for example if there are 10 posts on a page, I get 10 repeating subheadings as a result. I want to show subheading just once under the category name. Is there a way I can limit the number of results? p.s. relevant categories and prefetch thing was really useful to learn!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand what you want to do but you can search and access to Category elements by doing something like that:

```
categories=Category.objects.filter(name='NameYouWanttoSearch').values_list('subheading')
```

Comment: I just want to display category name and subheading on a page, I can use {{ category | title }} in template for the name but can't display the subheading of that category. If I use the code in my last quote, it repeats the subheading as many times as posts are on a category page.

Answer (score 0):

can add a model manager to the categories , take single instance and call it in templates instead of all.

```
class CategoryManager(models.Manager):

    def single_category(self):
        return self.get_queryset()[:1]

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    subheading = models.CharField(max_length=160)
    objects = CategoryManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

and in templates

```
{% for post in posts %}
{% for category in post.categories.single_category %}
{{ category.subheading }} 
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```